# TypeScript: unexpected import of jQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript

Why is the `$` in the program below resolved by the compiler, given that I'm not importing jQuery?

```
function f () {
   $('#loadFiles').click()   // ok 
   $$('#loadFiles').click()  // error, can't find name '$$'
}
```

I'm running the compiler (v2.0.3) as follows:

- `tsc Test.ts`, where `Test.ts` contains only the above text;
- with no `tsconfig.json` or `typings.json` in the containing folder.

I get that this may be related to the idiom commonly used in libraries like jQuery, but note that I'm *not* importing jQuery (as far as I know). But for some reason the compiler accepts '$' without complaining.

Can anyone reproduce this behaviour, or suggest how I might inadvertently be picking up a definition of '$'?

Comment: `$` and `$$` are completely, entirely different identifiers. jQuery doesn't assign itself to `$$` and using it typically won't work (unless some other library is providing it).

Comment: Indeed, that was the point of contrasting '$' and '$$'. My question is about the special treatment of '$', not the lack of special treatment for '$$'; clarified accordingly.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Do you have any typings or definition files included in your tsconfig? Posting the tsconfig might be a good idea, just in general.

Comment: HTMLElement has a click method, NodeLists do not;. $ is querySelector, $$ is querySelectorAll

Comment: @ssube No worries, I could've been clearer. There is no `tsconfig.json` in the folder; I'll clarify the question further. I must be doing something stupid, I just can't see what it is.

Comment: what browser is this in? can you log out the function signature for $? is the returned object an HTMLElement? can you check the returned object for $$? is it a NodeList?

Comment: @rlemon I'm not running the code, just trying to compile it.

Comment: ahh, nvm then. carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answering my own question]

First, I ran

```
tsc --traceResolution Test.ts
```

where `Test.ts` contains only the code

```
export function f () {
   $('#loadFiles').click()   // ok
}
```

(adding 'export' to force modules), `tsconfig.json` is empty, and `typings` is not installed, shows the following on my Node installation:

```
======== Type reference directive 'jquery' was successfully resolved to '/home/rolyp/Repo/concurrent-objects/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts', primary: true. ========
```

Several other "type reference directives" are also resolved, correspondingly exactly to the [`@types` packages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files) I have installed. So the problem seems to be that installing an `@types` package makes certain definitions globally available, without having to import them.

This seems to be how things are currently, although it doesn't interact with Webpack, which doesn't know about these implicit uses of packages.

Comment: You downvoted my (factually correct) answer because there wasn't enough information in your question to solve the underlying problem?

Answer (score -1):

There is no special treatment of `$` in TypeScript.

Of course, if you've included a declaration for the `$` variable but not the `$$` variable, they'll behave differently. Not sure what else you would expect.

Comment: Ok, this is weird then. I'm running `tsc Test.ts` on a file that contains only the above text, with no `tsconfig.json` in that folder.

Comment: Added some more details to the question. Guess I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Discovered that `tsc` supports `--traceResolution`, which shows jQuery being picked up from an `@types` installation. Now to find out why that brings '$' into scope without having to import it anywhere.